# Find nth term of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve some problems regarding logic reasoning. One the questions is: Given the sequence $1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1...$, is there some simple non-recursive formula to compute its n-th term?

I would appreciate some hints or partial answers, since it doesn't seem trivial to me.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A002260.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the patterns clear, right.

So

$A_1 = 1$

$A_2,A_3 = 1,2$

$A_4,... A_6 = 1...3$

....

$A_{foo}, ... A_{bar} = 1....n$

Well, okay the index $foo = 1 + 2 + 3 + ..... +(n-1) + 1$ and the index $bar = 1 + 2 + 3 + .....+ (n-1) + n$

So we have $A_{1 + 2+ ... + (n -1) +1}- A_{1+2+...+(n-1) + n} = 1... n$

Or in other words $A_{1  + 2 + .... + (n - 1) + i} = i$.

Is there any way we can find a formula from that?

Would it help if I told you $1 + 2 + 3 + ..... + (n-1) = \frac {(n-1)n}{2}$ and that $1 + 2 + 3 + ..... + n = \frac {n(n+1)}{2}$?

So we have $A_{\frac {n(n+1)}{2} + i} = i$.

Can we make a formula from that?

Answer (score 0):

Define $t(k)=\frac{k(k+1)}2$ ($k$-th triangular number when $k\geq 1$, with $t(0)=0$ defined).  To find the term $a_n$ in your sequence for $n\geq 1$, find the largest $k$ so that $t(k)<n$ (note strict inequality here).  Then $a_n=n-t(k)$.  Is that close enough to a formula for you?